How to listen external keyboard inputs in service in Android using java?
I'm making app that have to associate external keyboard inputs with taps. Now I'm trying to make my app listen external keyboard but it was unsuccessful.
Here what i've tried:

Accessibility Service - it can listen ONLY inputs in EditTexts.
OnKeyListener - works perfectly, but only if it is activity. I've tried to use such thing with Overlay, here what i've done:
It is OverlayService class

public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
            windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null);
            TextView result = overlayView.findViewById(R.id.result_view);

            Button test = overlayView.findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
            test.setOnClickListener(v ->{
                stopService(MainActivity.intent);
            });

            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            windowManager.addView(overlayView, params);

            overlayView.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
                result.setText(result.getText().toString()+keyCode);
                overlayView.requestFocus();
                return false;
            });

            TextView isFocused = overlayView.findViewById(R.id.isfocused);

            overlayView.requestFocus();

    }

But when Im typing with my external bluetooth keyboard nothing happens even tho it works in activity. I've made check if overlay is focused and it always was focused. What am i doing wrong?

I successfully implemented the same requirement using an accessibility service by following these steps:

Create a service that extends the AccessibilityService.

Ensure your service configuration (accessibility_service_config.xml) includes the following attributes:
android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"

Register this new service in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Override the method protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) and implement your logic.

Don't forget to start your service from Settings > Accessibility before testing.


Note: This will involve manual steps

It seems to be manual steps to start the accessibility service. Is there any way to automatic launch of this service when external keyboard is inserted ?

Unfortunately no, as per the official android documentation "Starting an accessibility service is triggered exclusively by the user explicitly turning the service on in device settings."
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService
